# Using a variable from a previous function in another function

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way for me to use a variable from a previous function in the next function?

I don't want to make the variable global by putting it at the beginning of the code because it's a calculation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either you return it, or use a global variable. Also, include what you've tried.

Comment: Solved it, had to use a global variable. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

you can return it and use it in an other function:

```
def myfunction():
    s = "value that i want in the otherfunction"
    return s

def otherfunction():
    s = myfunction()
    print s
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming previous function is called `foo`, and next function is called `bar`.

You can do one of the following:

- Have `foo` return the variable, and then either call `foo` from `bar` or set `foo` as one of `bar`'s arguments (by using `*args` and `**kwargs`).
- Have `foo` return the variable, assign this to a variable in the context where both `foo` and `bar` are called, and then pass the variable to `bar` as an argument.